# Asp.net redirect to secure.mysite.in

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have SSL cretificate to my site. I want to redirect my website to secure.mywebsite.in. I have tried this for redirecting http to https.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(false) && HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal.Equals(false))
        {
            Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]
        + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
        }           
    }
```

How can I redirect from `www.mysite.in` to `secure.mysite.in` ?

Answer (score 0):

If your website running on different address for secure channel you can use "HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery" to get the path and query string append it to any fixed url, look at the code below

If Host is different

```
Response.Redirect("https://secure.mysite.in" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
```

If Host is same

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "https://"));
```